# Expectation of dice

Tags: probability, expected-value

> What is the expectation of $\frac{1}{N}$ where $N$ is the number of times you roll a fair dice in order to get the number $1$?

I know the expectation of $N$ is $6$, so surely the expectation of $\frac{1}{N}$ is $\frac16$?

Please could someone confirm if this is correct.

Comment: In the same way that the average of $2$ and $3$ gives $\frac{5}{2}$ while the average of $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ gives $\frac{5}{12}$, the expectation $E[f(X)]$ is not necessarily going to be $f(E[X])$.  You need to approach from first principles here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go with the definition of an expectational value:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[1/N] = \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\mathbb{P}[N = n]
\end{align*}
As you will know
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[N = n] = \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}
\end{align*}
Plug that in and you get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[1/N] = \frac{1}{6}\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1} = \frac{\log(6)}{5}
\end{align*}
according to WolframAlpha.

Comment: Think you made a typo maybe. I got the answer to be $\frac{\log(6)}{5}$

Comment: You're right, thanks, I fixed it